# Mongo collection structure migration

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm a relative newcomer to Mongodb and I've hit a situation that I don't quite see how I resolve. I have this field definition in a mongoose schema:

```
account_number: {
                type: String,
                index: false,
                required: false
            },
```

Which I am converting to

```
account_number: [
            {
                type: String,
                index: false,
                required: false
            }
        ],
```

Which is fine, the point I am stuck on is now converting the data still held in the previous definition into the new array format. How would I do this on the command line?

Edit:

I have this now:

```
    db.customers.find().snapshot().forEach(function (elem) {
    db.customers.update({_id: elem._id},{$unset: {account_number: 1}}); 
db.customers.update({_id: elem._id},{$push: {account_number: elem.account_number}});});
```

Which is recreating the property as an array, but it is blank.

Comment: (to my knowledge) that's not possible with a single update statement, as you cannot refer to current values within an update (as opposed to e.g. SQL). What you'll have to do is iterate through the collection and update each document step by step.

Comment: So each document will now have multiple account numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so this is what I got working:

```
db.customers.find().forEach(function (elem) {
  db.customers.update({_id: elem._id}, {$unset: {account_number: 1}}); 
  db.customers.update({_id: elem._id}, {$push: {account_number: elem.account_number}});
});
```

For anyone who finds this